# In elasticsearch, how to group by value inside nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

Say, I have following documents:

1st doc:

```
{
  productName: "product1",
  tags: [
    {
      "name":"key1",
      "value":"value1"
    },
    {
      "name":"key2",
      "value":"value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

2nd doc:

```
{
  productName: "product2",
  tags: [
    {
      "name":"key1",
      "value":"value1"
    },
    {
      "name":"key2",
      "value":"value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know if I want to group by productName, I could use a `terms` aggregation

```
"terms": {
    "field": "productName"
}
```

which will give me two buckets with two different keys "product1", "product2".

However, what should the query be if I would like to group by tag key? i.e. I would like to group by tag with name==key1, then I am expecting one bucket with key="value1"; while if I group by tag with name==key2, I am expecting the result to be two buckets with keys "value2", "value3".

What should the query look like if I would like to group by the 'value' inside a nested array but not group by the 'key'? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) terms aggregation is what you're looking for.

With the two documents you posted, this query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "product_name_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "product_name"
         }
      },
      "nested_tags": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "tags"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "tags_name_terms": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "tags.name"
               }
            },
            "tags_value_terms": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "tags.value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

returns this:

```
{
   "took": 67,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "product_name_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": []
      },
      "nested_tags": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "tags_name_terms": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "key1",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "key2",
                  "doc_count": 2
               }
            ]
         },
         "tags_value_terms": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "value1",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "value2",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "value3",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a9a172f41dbd520d5e61063a9686055681110522

**EDIT: Filter by Nested Value**

As per your comment, if you want to filter the nested results by a value (of the nested results), you can add another "layer" of aggregation making use of the [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) as follows:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "nested_tags": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "tags"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "filter_tag_name": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "tags.name": "key1"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "tags_name_terms": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "tags.name"
                     }
                  },
                  "tags_value_terms": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "tags.value"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 10,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "nested_tags": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "filter_tag_name": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "tags_name_terms": {
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
               "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
               "buckets": [
                  {
                     "key": "key1",
                     "doc_count": 2
                  }
               ]
            },
            "tags_value_terms": {
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
               "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
               "buckets": [
                  {
                     "key": "value1",
                     "doc_count": 2
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the updated code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/507c3aabf36b8f6ed8bb076c8c1b8552097c5458

Comment: Thanks but what if I only want to group by the value only associate with one tag key? So I'm expecting some way that could allow me to group by tags.value that only associate with tags.name==key2 without returning any bucket associate with key1's values. Is there such way?